# Function to create objects by passing an array of parameters to __construct()?

Tags: php, class, object, instantiation

I wonder if anyone know of a function to fully pragmatically create a class object similar to how call_user_func_array() works. What I want to do is pass a varying amount of parameters to the __construct().

I need something like:

```
$class = create_object('myobject', $array);
```

To have the behavior of;

```
$class = new myobject($array[0], $array[1], $array[2], ...);
```

Note: This is for a universal framework component so passing the whole array as the first construct parameter is not an option.

Comment: [How to "invoke" a class instance in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1542717/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with PHP's features. You can unpack arrays as argument lists:

```
function create_object($type, array $args = [])
{
    return new $type(...$args);
}
```

Not sure the need for this though.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I see the three dots is actually a thing in PHP 5.6 called splat operator. I presume there is no other option for PHP 5.4+ which is the minimum requirement for this platform.

Comment: Yes the three dots ... https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Answer (score 0):

For PHP <5.6 this can be achieved using ReflectionClass.

```
function create_object($class_name, $args=array()) {
  $reflect = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
  return $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
}
```

Note: ReflectionClass is twice as slow as the splat operator.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648651/1135440